# elasticSearch: bool query with multiple values on one field

Tags: elasticsearch

This works:

```
 GET /bitbucket$$pull-request-activity/_search
 {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "prid": "12343"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "repoSlug": "com.xxx.vserver"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But I would like to capture multiple `prid`s in one call.
This does not work however:

```
 GET /bitbucket$$pull-request-activity/_search


{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "prid": "[12343, 11234, 13421]"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "repoSlug": "com.xxx.vserver"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using **must** in your **bool query**, then this represents **logical AND**, so be sure that all the documents that you are Matching of the `prid` field, should also match with `"repoSlug": "com.xxx.vserver"`.

If none of the documents match with `"repoSlug": "com.xxx.vserver"`, then no result will return.

And, if only 2 documents match, then only 2 of them will be returned in the search result, and not all the documents.

Adding Working example with mapping, sample docs and search query

**Index Sample Data :**

```
{
  "id":"1",
  "message":"hello"
}
{
  "id":"2",
  "message":"hello"
}
{
  "id":"3",
  "message":"hello-bye"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "id": "[1, 2, 3]"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "message": "hello"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result :**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "foo14",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.5924306,
        "_source": {
          "id": "1",
          "message": "hello"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "foo14",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1.4903541,
        "_source": {
          "id": "3",
          "message": "hello-bye"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "foo14",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.081605,
        "_source": {
          "id": "2",
          "message": "hello"
        }
      }
    ]
```